# Adding/subtracting from a variable when increasing it by a value over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I have water being drained down from its max value to 0 in a certain time period (timeToDrain in this code). What I'm wonder is why I can't modify this value (`water`) at all when I do something like

```
water += 1;
```

My code:

```
public float water,waterMax,w;

void ddrainWater() {
        float timeToDrain = 160; //seconds

        float timeRemaining = timeToDrain - w;

        w += Time.deltaTime;
        water = Mathf.Lerp(waterMax, 0, w / timeToDrain);
    }
```

Again, I am not exactly sure how to solve something like this.

Expected: being able to do

```
water += 0.2f;
```

But water is constantly being set back to the value that was given to it by `Mathf.Lerp()`. Is there any way I can add/subtract a value from this variable? Maybe something to do with the variable 'w'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Because of the Lerp

That Lerp call *does not in any way* care what the current value of `water` is, it will overwrite it based on `w`.

If you want to *add* water, you need to *subtract* from `w` *or* not use Lerp and instead manage the draining speed yourself.

I can't provide an example fix, because how you want to handle things is how *you* want to handle things (and I don't have all your code).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are setting `water` to a new value through `water += value`, but then setting it to another value through the Lerp function which varies independently of the current value for `water`.

Your choices are to either: decrease `w` by an amount (perhaps replace `water += value` with `w -= (waterMax / timeToDrain) * value`), increase the `timeToDrain` by some value (perhaps replace `water += value` with `timeToDrain += (timeToDrain / waterMax) * value`), or to replace the Lerp function with something that uses the current water level rather than the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If you code what you say you looking for it actually would work fine - decrease current amount of water by draining happened since last tick:

```
 var amountDrainedSinceLastCheck = waterMax * Time.deltaTime / timeToDrain;
 water = water - amountDrainedSinceLastCheck;
```